# select a single column from Mysql DB using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql

How do I get values from a single column using sqlalchemy?

In MySQL

```
select id from request r where r.product_id = 1;
```

In Python

```
request = meta.tables['request']
request.select(request.c.product_id==1).execute().rowcount   
27L

>>> request.select([request.c.id]).where(request.c.product_id==1).execute()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.freebsd-6.3-RELEASE-i386/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 2616,     in select
File "build/bdist.freebsd-6.3-RELEASE-i386/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 305, in select
File "build/bdist.freebsd-6.3-RELEASE-i386/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 5196, in __init__
File "build/bdist.freebsd-6.3-RELEASE-i386/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 1517, in _literal_as_text
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected.
```

Comment: I found the answer, I have to use the general select vs the table select.

Leaving this incase more folks find it useful.

    conn = engine.connect()
    stmt = select([request.c.id]).where(request.c.product_id==1)
    conn.execute(stmt).rowcount
    27L

Comment: You could add this as an answer so it will be easier to read.

Comment: Low reputation, doesn't let me answer my own question :(

Comment: Maybe you could try to edit the question to include the solution but I'm not sure that it is the right way to do it.

Comment: It let me answer it after 8 hours. Updated with answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, I have to use the general select vs the table select.

Leaving this incase more folks find it useful.

```
conn = engine.connect()
stmt = select([request.c.id]).where(request.c.product_id==1)
conn.execute(stmt).rowcount
27L
```